# pandas timeseries slicing: between_time returns NaN value while using inside the query operator np.where

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, numpy, jupyter-notebook

I'm trying to label a certain period of time that occurs repeatedly in a time series data set. I'm using between_time() inside of a np.where(). It returns a NaN value.

*What am I missing?*

```py
import pandas as pd 
import numpy as np
data_df = pd.read_csv("data.csv")
data_df['Datetime'] = pd.to_datetime(data_df['Date'] + ' ' + data_df['Time'])
data_df = data_df.set_index('Datetime')
data_df['label'] =pd.Series(np.where(data_df['Time'].between_time('16:00','9:00'), "time1", "time2"))
data_df.head()
```

[Image of the table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ey7fg.png)

Answer (score 0):

There is an alternative solution using `apply` which may be a little tricky but do the work

```
df['Label'] = df['time'].apply(lambda x : 'time1' if x < '09:00:00' and x > '06:00:00' else 'time2')

print(df[df['Label']=='time1'].head()) #show time1 values
```

Comment: Thanks! but what is that I have to do by using between_time?